# Pygame seems to flip rows and columns?

Tags: python, pygame

It seems like every time I create something in pygame, I have to switch the rows and columns for it to print correctly. For example, if I have:

```
for col in range(COLS): 
    board[3][col] = 'tree'
```

I set up a draw function to draw a sprite whenever the board cell is equal to 3. However, it draws a vertical line of trees instead of horizontal. Since I want to iterate over all the columns in the 3rd row, the correct output should be a horizontal line of trees.

This is just one example out of many, but does anyone have any clue why pygame is doing this?

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with PyGame you don't event use PyGame code in your problem. You have rather problem with data organization. You keep data as `[row][column]` but maybe you shoud keep it as `[column][row]`. `[row][column]` means `(y,x)` but all drawing functions use `(x,y)` . Or you have to remeber that your data (and  matrix in math) uses `(y, x)` and all drawing systems use `(x,y)`

Comment: Please post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is because in real world we use two systems to describe position.

First uses `(x,y)` and you can see in

- computer screen
- math - point on graph
- all drawing modules (not only `PyGame`, not only in `Python`)

Second uses `(y,x)` and you can see in

- matrix in math `(row, column)`
- room's numbers `(floor, door)`
- tickets in cimena `(row, place)`
- geolocation `(latitude, longitude)`

You use second system `(y,x)` to keep data but Pygame use first system `(x,y)` to draw it
so you have to remeber to switch `(y,x)` to `(x,y)` (`[row][column]` to `[column][row]`)
or you have to keep data as `[column][row]` (`(x,y)`)